# Connect two hall sensors to single analog pin of MCU to determine upper and lower limits

Tags: microcontroller, analog, hall-effect

I have motor which is rotating a shaft. I can rotate it only for 200 degrees so I am planning to use hall sensors and magnets on shaft to determine upper and lover rotation limits. Catch is I don't want to waste 2 analog pins for this. So, what is the best way to connect two hall sensors to single analog pin so I would know when one of the limits is reached and if it is upper or lower. Hall sensor which I use outputs 1.6 V without magnetic filed and goes 1 V down or 1 V up when I bring magnet close other way around. Supply voltage is 3.3 V.

Comment: Can you use hall switches and 2 digital pins instead?

Comment: Also please provide a part number for the hall sensor you're using now.

Comment: Hall sensor is AH3503 and I would like to use hall sensor rather than hall switch.

Comment: Well right off I can tell you that your supply voltage is too low. It needs to be at least 4.5V for that sensor. It may work somewhat below that but some aspect of it's performance is likely compromised, otherwise they would have specified a lower minimum voltage.

Comment: I know, but I have tested it and it is working down to 2.5 V. In this case I don't care much about linearity.

Comment: _"goes 1 V down or 1 V up when I bring magnet close other way around"_ - so why are you using 2 hall sensors?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I had a feeling that I am doing something stupid. (I wanted to use 2 sensors with one magnet). This is the right solution. I will use 1 sensor and two magnets, one with south and another with north facing out. Thank you. Could you post an answer?

Comment: @BruceAbbott KISS principle strikes again :) simple and elegant

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use one ADC input pin to get two results.
Here is a brief diagram showing.
Combine two analog signals into one.
And use a operating amplifier to execute signal conditioning.
Choose appropriate resistors to match ADC input requirement.

[image]